# React Native app "full screen" in new cellphones

Tags: react-native, statusbar, android-9.0-pie, iphone-x, android-navigation-bar

My goal is to make an app full screen with the status bar visible in Android and in IPhone, like in Expo but in React Native

Here is what is happening:

[image]

My goal is to remove this gray part and make the app occupy this part and at the same time show the status bar, like in Expo.

I already tried this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar.html#sethidden

But all the gray top became black and without status bar

I already tried add this to styles.xml in Android:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

But changed nothing (and will work just in Android)

Answer (score 8):

Out of the box option.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }
}
```

or another way is to use true [Immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) in android. Either you can go for native approach or find any RN modules that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StatusBar to set those options as follows:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#FF573300'); 
      StatusBar.setTranslucent(true)
     }, []);

     return(...);
}
```

The last zeros in the color code indicates the opacity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Add this code in your Android Native mainActivity onCreate Method

```java
    /**
     * For fullscreen mode
     */
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
```

> Like this

[image: Like this]

Comment: To make this work, make sure to add `import android.view.View;` to the top

Answer (score 0):

If it only android.

1- Create `FullScreenModule.java and FullScreenPackage.java` and put them under `android/app/main/java/com/Your-App-Name`

```
// FullScreenModule.java

package com.your-app-name;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.UiThreadUtil;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;


public class FullScreenModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "FullScreen";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void enable() {
        UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    );
                }
            }
        );

    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void disable() {
        UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    );
                }
            }
        );

    }

    FullScreenModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }
}
```

And `FullScreenPackage.java`

// FullScreenPackage.java

```
package com.your-app-name;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class FullScreenPackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
                              ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    modules.add(new FullScreenModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
  }

}
```

Next in your `MainApplication.java` put those

```
import com.your-app-name.FullScreenPackage;
```

and add the package under `getPackages()` `packages.add(new FullScreenPackage());`

lastly create `fullScrean.{js or tsx}` file somewhere that containe

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.FullScreen;
```

Now import the module `import FullScreen from './fullScrean';`

and then simple `FullScreen.enable() / FullScreen.disable()` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Use  react-native-fullscreen-chz

> **yarn add react-native-fullscreen-chz**

```js
import FullScreenAndroid from 'react-native-fullscreen-chz'

FullScreenAndroid.enable();
```

## Styles.xml

##### android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    
             <!-- Add this line for notched devices. -->
            <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">shortEdges</item> 
        </style>
    </resources>
```

more info : [react-native-fullscreen-chz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fullscreen-chz)